# Enable GA and other trackers only for production when assets are prebuilt with webpack

Tags: web, google-analytics, webpack, frontend

I'm shipping frontend application I want to track stats for (GA and other trackers). The app is prebuilt with webpack on CI and I'd like to have the same bundle to be shipped to both staging and prod environments. 
But there is an issue with that: if I enable trackers during build time they'll be enabled on both envs.

One way I see is to add set `window.enableTrackers = true` flag in `index.html` when sending app code from server and then decide whether to install trackers or not, but it seems to be pretty ugly solution.

Is there any other way u use to do it? Checking domain name on the client maybe? Something like:

```
if(document.location.hostname === 'prod.example.com') {
  // enable trackers
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be best resolved at the time the compilation is made by configuring Webpack differently for the production and stage bundles, where you could use the CLI [`--define`](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/cli#plugins) or [`--env`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2254#issuecomment-203528744) to explicitly enable tracking.

If you don't resolve the inclusion of tracking during the compilation, then you will have to resort to other means. One option is to evaluate during runtime whether the GA script should be loaded in the document. Here's an example of a Rect element that will load the script only if the hostname matches a configurable regular expression:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'

const production = new RegExp(RE_PRODUCTION_HOST) 

export const ga = window.ga = window.ga || function () {
  (ga.q = ga.q || []).push(arguments)
}

export class Analytics extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };

  componentDidMount () {
    // Runtime evaluation for loading the GA script
    if (!self.location.hostname.match(production)) {
      return
    }

    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'
    script.async = true

    document.body.appendChild(script)
  }

  render () {
    ga.l = +new Date()

    ga('create', this.props.id, 'auto')
    ga('send', 'pageview')

    return null
  }
}
```

Here, I can still safely define `RE_PRODUCTION_HOST` to be configured to `production.com` or even `^(www.)?production.com%` and I can change it during test compilations to make assertions.

Another option is to add [filters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en#PredefinedFilters) in Google Analytics that will include/exclude results depending on the hostname. This won't require you to make any further changes in your code.

Comment: Key point it that I don't want to do different builds/compilations for different envs, so webpack define does not help much here. I'm using it anyway to define trackers IDs but that's all. 

What I ended up with was to further use webpack's define to define TRACKED_DOMAINS to say `production.com`. Then when page gets opened I check whether `document.location.hostname` matches any of the TRACKED_DOMAINS and if so, I execute trackers installation code. So this looks similar to what you posted above